# Recording instruments on Zoom H6

Tags: audio-recording, portable-recorder, zoom-h4n, recorder, zoom-h6

I just bought a new Zoom H6 with a purpose of recording digital Piano and maybe record my voice with online teaching.

However, regarding the Piano recording, I tried first plugging a single TRS cable between any of zoom's channel and the digital piano.

The issue comes here, I cant come with a high quality recording, as with high volume intake I get distorted sound and with lower ones I get a low sound. In other words I cant get high clear (rich) sound without distortion.

*I Tried applying some limiter.

*Failed with low cut filters as it corrupt the notes sound

*Tried recording with X/Y mic that comes with the zoom ... which  does a pretty good job but this comes to the second problem which is ambient sound, or in other words the room noise even after closing all windows and any thing doing noises.

This applies to when I try to record my voice as well . It seems low cut filters like not working properly or I am missing something

So please advice me in both digital and acoustic (voice or piano) recording

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the distortion is the high output level from your digital piano - you need to turn it down so it is as loud as possible without distorting, so it doesn't overload your input stage on the Zoom.

Using a limiter or filters here are not the answer. Get your audio right on the way in - you can always amplify it later.

Regarding your mic picking up noise, yes, you need to reduce ambient noise as much as possible.

We have loads of posts here on noise reduction and or input gain. Worth having a look around the site.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helps a lot ... however the only thing I want to make sure its true is that the zoom stock x/y mic should not be recording ambient sound right ? And what keywords shall I be using while searching ? For example"removing ambient sound in zoom"?  From here I can start my homework through posts...

Comment: Or is that as well removed in post production as amplifying the sound ? I am totally new to the recordings ... so sorry for the annoying questions

Comment: all microphones will record ambient sound. But all have different characteristics of how their gain physically corresponds to direction. See other posts here on directional mics, omni mics etc. Your Zoom has unidirectional mics (a cardioid polar pattern) so most sensitive to sound directly in front of them, but you still need to minimise all background noise.